# Set ringtone from a path in android

Tags: java, android, ringtone, ringtonemanager

I had a path of song, example:

> /sdcard/music/song/song.mp3

so I want to implement a button click that this song will be set ringtone
.Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Get the path of your file to set as ringtone

```
String filePath= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/YourFolder/Ringtones/myRingTone.mp3";

    File ring = new File("filePath");
```

Set it as ringtone by using:

```
 Uri path = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(ring.getAbsolutePath());
 RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(getApplicationContext(), RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,path)
```

Note: Add this permission in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" ></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 0):

first you need to get file with getassert functions , we will call him filesong here `MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(mainactivity.this, filesong);
        mPlayer.start();`